# Seam <s:link> and link caption

Tags: jsf, richfaces, seam

In one of my pages

```
<s:link value="/index.seam"><h:outputText value="#{messages.home}"/></s:link>
```

renders as

```
<a href="/acm20/index.seam?cid=64" id="j_id9">/index.seamHome</a>
```

How can I get rid of the "/index.seam" in front of  "Home" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these two are exactly the same:

```
<s:link value="/index.seam" />
<s:link><h:outputText value="/index.seam"/></s:link>
```

You have to write

```
<s:link view="/index.xhtml"><h:outputText value="#{messages.home}"/></s:link>
```

Or of course the one I prefer:

```
<s:link view="/index.xhtml" value="#{messages.home}"/>
```

The key is to use the `view` attribute, not `value` on s:link

Why are you using `#{messages.home}` btw? If you want to use the message property file, the correct syntax is `#{messages['home']}`

Comment: Thanks! About messages, I have seen it used in both ways on http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.0.3.CR1/reference/en-US/html/i18n.html#d0e9211